# How to set Minimum Order Quantiy (MOQ) for a category in magento?

Tags: magento

How to add Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart for a category.

In Magento (ver. 1.6.2.0) backend, System > Configuration > Inventory > Product Stock Options tab, you can set the 'Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart' but for Customer Group; not for Category.

We have lots of categories having absolutely different kinds of items and need different MOQs for specified category.

How would I force a minimum of 6 products from the jewellery category and 7 dozen from the bra category?

Thanks, Shaman

Comment: I would suggest you to check out catalog and cart price rules. Moreover it seems that such complex behaviour might be achieved only via custom module.

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov Thank you for your response. I checked out the catalog and cart price rules, it helps a little but it doesn't work as wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe would not be natively possible with Magento. Magento natively provides a 1:many relationship with categories and products,

Ie. A product can be in many categories

What you propose would induce a *race condition* for a product whereby there could be 2 possible critera for a product's inventory controls if the product exists in more than one category.

Eg. If you set `Category A` to have a *MOQ* of 6, and `Category B` to have a *MOQ* of 10 and `Product C` exists in both - which rule does it inherit (highest/lowest)?

As a result, this isn't going to be natively possible, but you could build a custom module to achieve it.

### Either ...

**Via a `category->save()` observer**

You could create a custom attribute for the category - MOQ, then have your module 'listen' to the category save, and iterate through all products accordingly to set the MOQ for said products.

**Advantages** - More granular control per product, no speed impact/overheads for frontend

**Disadvantages** - Slow to save category

### Or

**By modifying the `isSaleable()` function**

You could rewrite the standard function which determines if a product is saleable. In your modified function, check categories of said product, obtain the MOQ (highest/lowest - *whichever*) then `return true;` or `return false;` accordingly.

**Advantages** - Less administration hanging around, stops having to continually update indexes at a product level needlessly

**Disadvantages** - Slower to check if product is saleable (frontend would seem slower)

---

Either way, you need to build a custom module, or seek a professional to make one for you.

Comment: hey bro can tell me how you was able to achieve it