# How can I set minimum order value for particular category in magento

Tags: magento

i want to add multiple minimum order value for multiple categories. How can i do it. I tried it but there is a solution for quantity of product restriction but not for min order value for particular category.Please give me suggestion and if there any extension is available for this please provide me link.

Comment: Dis you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281228/how-to-set-minimum-order-quantiy-moq-for-a-category-in-magento ?

Comment: what you want to achieve if it meet with your parameter ? you wanna give discount or wanna allow checkout if only match the criteria ?

Comment: I want to add 3 types of hotel 1